# How to format the value of input[time] when bound to Date()-object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am binding a variable to an input-field of type time, but the displayed format is wrong.

It displays the time like this: `08:54:30,088`
What I actually need is a format like this: `08:54`.

I tried to set the value of the input field with a filter ( `value={{ datetime.date | date : 'HH:mm' }}` ) but my editor says the way I do this is wrong. Any ideas?

Here the compltete code:

### HTML

```
 <input id="rep_time" class="form-control" type="time" ng-model="datetime.time" value={{ datetime.date | date : 'HH:mm' }}>
```

### JS

```
 app.controller( 'newCtrl', function( $scope ) {  

     $scope.datetime = {
         date: new Date(),
         time: new Date()
       };
 } );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I circumvented the problem by defining the Date()-object a bit. It works but I don't like this way of double defining.

### HTML

```
 <input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="datetime.date" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2016-01-01" required />

 <input class="form-control" type="time" ng-model="datetime.time">
```

### JS

```
$scope.datetime = {
        date: new Date(),
        time: ''
    };

$scope.datetime.time = new Date(
            $scope.datetime.date.getFullYear(),
            $scope.datetime.date.getMonth() + 1,
            $scope.datetime.date.getDate(),
            $scope.datetime.date.getHours(),
            $scope.datetime.date.getMinutes() );
```

### UPDATE of js

with the idea of using a $filter from **Jimbrooism** I found a shorter way!

```
$scope.datetime = {
     date: new Date(),
     time: new Date( $filter( 'date' )( new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' ) )
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls check out this

```js
var app = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
  $scope.datetime = {
         date: new Date(),
         time: $filter('date')( new Date(), 'HH:mm')
       };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input id="rep_time" class="form-control" type="time" ng-model="datetime.time" >
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get the error that the variable is no Date-object. Error-Link displayed in console: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ngModel/datefmt?p0=09%3A57

Comment: @SvenYa I just add a filter only , the problem is you are giving a string instead of date

Comment: You have to convert the value to date

Comment: I would then need to do something like this to make it work:

`$scope.datetime = {
            date: new Date(),
            time: new Date()
        };
        $scope.datetime.time = new Date( 
   $filter( 'date' )( $scope.datetime.time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' ) );`

Comment: still doesn't work if you don't create a Date()-object. If you use $filter you always have a String which will not be accepted by angularjs as ng-model for the input[time]. And it also doesn't work if you just say HH:mm in the filter. The date must also be given.

Comment: pls comment you input

Comment: I used your $filter-suggestion and added an answer myself mentioning you and edited it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input id="rep_time" class="form-control" type="time" ng-model="datetime.time" data-ng-value={{ datetime.date | date : 'shortTime'}}>
```

Comment: Did try, getting the following error: _http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7B&p4=%7B_. My editor error-marks the ` | ` and the ` ' ` in the data-ng-value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the model to be bound to an input element?
Applying filters to input fields usually generates warnings or errors, since filters are one-way, and binding existing value to input and then changing them there is a two-way binding.

If you don't need to be able to change the element, consider changing input to something else, like

```
<div ng-bind="datetime.date | date : 'HH:mm'"></div>
```

If you have to use input, Jimbroosim's answer would work.

Comment: yeah it needs to be an input field 'cause the user should be able to change it from it's default value.