# AngularJS - Parsing ng-model to date/time

Tags: angularjs, date, time

Is there any way for Angular to take the string from the date/time inputs? Currently, I have this input, for example:

```
<input class="admin-input" type="time" ng-model="newEvent.endHour"/>
```

I'd like to show the value in model as HH:mm but, when I print its value, it shows the full date plus the full time. Is there anyway to get just the string shown in the input (HH:mm format) into the ng-model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format the value of input\[time\] when bound to Date()-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976716/how-to-format-the-value-of-inputtime-when-bound-to-date-object)

Comment: Tried that and still didn't work. Seems that i will have to parse it in the controller, as it also shows 1 day and 1 hour less than those shown in the input

Answer (score 2):

You can use the angular **[`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** filter,

```
<input class="admin-input" type="time" ng-model="newEvent.endHour | date:'HH:mm'"/>
```

**EDIT**
If you want to bind it to a model then add a watch and filter it inside the controller,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.endHour = new Date();
  $scope.$watch('endHour', function(newValue) {
    $scope.endHour = $filter('date')(newValue, 'HH:mm');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <input type="datetime" ng-model="endHour" class="form-control" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems you can't assign a filter to the ng-model, it doesn't work

Comment: i would suggest you to do it on the controller unless you are displaying it in expression

Comment: Still the same, it seems like it will always send the full date in both time and dates: 2017-03-13T23:00:00.000Z (also timezone is incorrect)

Comment: did you check the demo

Comment: Yes, I did the same, which also is like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976716/how-to-format-the-value-of-inputtime-when-bound-to-date-object